# Smart contract in Solidity: call a function from a contract written in Vyper

Tags: solidity, vyper

I'm writing a contract in Solidity, in which I'm trying to call a function from another contract written in Vyper.

To do so, I've checked the corresponding function in the ABI of the Vyper contract, which is:

```
{"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function","name":"mint","inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"outputs":[]}
```

Therefore, in my interface, I declare the following:

```
function mint(address _to, uint256 _value) external;
```

And I call this function from a function mint2 in my contract (that's the only thing I do in mint2).

I can compile and deploy the contract without any problem, but when i'm trying to call mint2, it fails. The function mint from the Vyper contract works, so it is obviously a problem related to the interface but I don't know what.

Would you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the interface. The transaction might revert inside the vyper execution for some reason. My suggestion is debugging the transaction in a local forked chain to see for what exact reason it reverts.